# How do I add a UIBarButtonItem to a UIToolbar with both text and an image in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I add a `UIBarButtonItem` to a `UIToolbar` with both text and an image in it? Take a look at the example image I show. It's exactly what I'm trying to do.

[image: Here's the image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all create a UIButton, with Image and title.

Then add that Button to BarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Comment: Yes, but does that imply that I have to completely style the button to look exactly like a normal UIBarButton? The advantage of using a standard UIBarButtonItem is to get the shine in the middle of the button.

Comment: @Ethan Allen :For that you need to design the button image as like the barbuttonItem. Every one will do like that only.

Answer (score 1):

add custom buttom to toolbar set this property to that button add label on button for text

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment =  UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create `UIView` with `UILabel` and `UIImage` as subviews. Then create `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of reference link will guide you to how to implement UIBarButtonItem to a UIToolbar with text and an image....
You just modify the code as per your requirements.

1. [UIToolbar UIBarButtonItem with both image and title has very dim text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533238/uitoolbar-uibarbuttonitem-with-both-image-and-title-has-very-dim-text/3956029#3956029)
2. [add image to UIBarButtonItem for UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299805/add-image-to-uibarbuttonitem-for-uitoolbar/3299983#3299983)